# How do I remove my Windows 8 Preview installation from the Windows Store's list of "other PCs" that I have apps installed on?

Tags: windows-8, windows-8-preview, windows-store

It's cluttering up the list, and confuses me because it has the same name as my later Windows 8 release installation on the same PC.

Comment: You should be able to remove the device from within your Microsoft Account.

Comment: If you're talking about account.live.com, I don't see any such option there...

Comment: So you are unable to manage anything connected to the Permissions of your account?  I have a single Windows Store application listed under `Permissions -> Apps and Services`

Comment: All I have under Apps and Services is some "IM+ Live" thing that I've never heard of...

Comment: Oh, wait, I actually used to use an app called IM+; maybe that's it? But nothing about any other apps, or any devices, shows up there.